# Property [articles] does not exist on this collection instance. laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, blogs

help or assist as it does not turn out to make sorting on categories, I can not understand as to solve this problem. 
I recently study laravel.

Controller: `class ArticlesController`

```
    public function showAll ($category_id)
{
    $categories = Category::where('name', $category_id)->get();
    return view('categories')->with(compact('categories', 'articles'));
}
```

This view from which I want to go into categories. `site.blade.php`

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
        <li><a class="nav-link text-white" href={{route('articlesShow', ['id'=>$category->id]) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/categories/{category_id}', 'ArticlesController@showAll')->name('articlesShow');
```

Model: Category

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'category_id');
}
```

Representation in which does not get to get: `categories.blade.php`

```
    @foreach($categories->articles as $article)
           <div class="col-6 col-lg-4"> <!--Post -->
             <img src="{{ asset('upload/image/1.jpg') }}" width="255" alt="..." class="rounded img_size">
             <h4> {{ $article->title }}</h4>
             <h6>Category: <a href="/"> {{ $article->category->name }}</a></h6>
             <h6>Author: {{ $article->author }}</h6>
             <p>{{ $article->text }} </p>
             <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ route('articleShow', ['id' =>$article->id]) }}"> More &raquo;</a></p>
           </div><!--EndPost-->
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

$categories is an array that contains categories, and the articles property belongs to a category, therefore you have to loop the categories before you can access the articles.

try this:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
 @foreach($category->articles as $article)
       <div class="col-6 col-lg-4"> <!--Post -->
         <img src="{{ asset('upload/image/1.jpg') }}" width="255" alt="..." class="rounded img_size">
         <h4> {{ $article->title }}</h4>
         <h6>Category: <a href="/"> {{ $article->category->name }}</a></h6>
         <h6>Author: {{ $article->author }}</h6>
         <p>{{ $article->text }} </p>
         <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ route('articleShow', ['id' =>$article->id]) }}"> More &raquo;</a></p>
       </div><!--EndPost-->
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. The error does not produce, but when you click on the link, it does not display any.

Comment: try {{ route('articleShow', ['categories_id' =>$category->id]) }} instead of {{ route('articleShow', ['id' =>$article->id]) }}

Comment: Thanks, now displays articles, but in the menu when you click on the category, another category disappears and in the place it appears the one to which it clicked. The code in the controller is this: $categories = Category::with('articles')->where('id', $category_id)->get();
        return view('categories')->with(compact('categories', $categories));

Answer (score 0):

First of all: use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Assuming, your `ArticlesController@showAll` method should display all articles for a given category id, your query should look like this

```
public function showAll ($category_id)
{
    $categoryArticles = Category::with('articles')->where('id', $category_id)->get();
    return view('categories')->with('categoryArticles', $categoryArticles);
}
```

Then to display all articles for the given category (assuming an article has only one category), this could be one way:

```
@foreach($categoryArticles->articles as $article)
           <div class="col-6 col-lg-4"> <!--Post -->
             <img src="{{ asset('upload/image/1.jpg') }}" width="255" alt="..." class="rounded img_size">
             <h4> {{ $article->title }}</h4>
             <h6>Category: <a href="/"> {{ $categoryArticles->name }}</a></h6>
             <h6>Author: {{ $article->author }}</h6>
             <p>{{ $article->text }} </p>
             <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ route('articleShow', ['id' =>$article->id]) }}"> More &raquo;</a></p>
           </div><!--EndPost-->
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. 
It gives the same error: Property [articles] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /home/vagrant/Code/nexta/resources/views/categories.blade.php)

Comment: I updated my dummy code to rename the variable to `$categoryArticles` because you are already using the variable `$category` in some previous blade templates. This should work now.

Comment: Thank you that you want to help, but you get this error: Undefined variable: categoryArticles(View:/home/vagrant/Code/nexta/resources/views/categories.blade.php) 
It turns out that when you go to the final representation there is not this variable and why this happens.

Comment: I apologize, the error is different: Property [articles] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /home/vagrant/Code/nexta/resources/vie‌​ws/categories.blade.‌​php)

Comment: @Иван: have you also updated your showAll() function? What is the output if you dd($categoryArticles)?

Comment: Here's the transition that displays: https://i.stack.imgur.com/keTC5.png